# Filtering JSON curl results with jq selectors

Tags: json, web-services, jq, json-query

I have the following multi-record JSON structure coming as a response from a web service:

```
  [
    {
    "model": "analytics.request",
    "pk": 89,
    "fields": {
        "intent": "GetUserAccountInformation",
        "sub_intent": "",
        "request_text": "what is my balance",
        "response_text": "You have $111,111.11 and owe $111,111. Shall I break that down?",
        "session_id": "1v69yiptamgse1niap51zr2o9x154169081480766b2d6b7-d3ce-4166-9292-c4669a3dfc14",
        "user_id": "amzn1.ask.account.AHMFB2H7ZXMSCB5TLPYWCPBJGWGHFYQZ6OPPMEPQ7CT2LZXNPAFJMJELXXCCTEZ2JUE5PXRSBJHJTO3AVXT3C63AOEZLIEP3D3HIFBT5M23G4ORENFRT54AAK7I4X2HCORXJAB2UGQAHPE2TC75F2GWWZWSPO2CWEAZJJN7LJYFWEYHEJDLNQ6FSUD5LQWKBUC347K3IF32IV3I",
        "device_id": "amzn1.ask.account.AHMFB2H7ZXMSCB5TLPYWCPBJGWGHFYQZ",
        "device_type": "alexa",
        "device_model": "NA",
        "device_os": "alexa",
        "elapsed_time": 23286,
        "region": "NA",
        "latitude": 0,
        "longitude": 0,
        "date": "2018-11-08T15:31:48.757+0000",
        "ext_session_id": "",
        "ext_user_id": "",
        "score": 1,
        "platform_type": "alexa",
        "platform_user_id": "amzn1.ask.account.AHMFB2H7ZXMSCB5TLPYWCPBJGWGHFYQZ6OPPMEPQ7CT2LZXNPAFJMJELXXCCTEZ2JUE5PXRSBJHJTO3AVXT3C63AOEZLIEP3D3HIFBT5M23G4ORENFRT54AAK7I4X2HCORXJAB2UGQAHPE2TC75F2GWWZWSPO2CWEAZJJN7LJYFWEYHEJDLNQ6FSUD5LQWKBUC347K3IF32IV3I",
        "platform_conversation_id": "amzn1.echo-api.session.9122211c-7fa8-43ae-b7e3-e56ebbdacc01",
        "registered": false,
        "segment_names": [
            "Seg0715080610AM",
            "Seg0715071857AM",
            "Seg0715070437AM",
            "Seg0715063307AM",
            "Seg0715054215AM",
            "Seg0715054027AM",
            "Seg0715053845AM",
            "Seg0715053646AM",
            "Seg0715053156AM",
            "Seg0715052407AM",
            "Seg0715045748AM",
            "Seg0714145246PM",
            "Seg0714135150PM",
            "Seg0714134041PM",
            "Seg0714012505AM",
            "Seg0714004152AM",
            "Seg0714002843AM",
            "Seg0713235444PM",
            "Seg0713230241PM",
            "Seg0713230030PM",
            "Seg0713225825PM",
            "Seg0713225548PM",
            "Seg0713225028PM",
            "Seg0713224159PM",
            "Seg0713220356PM",
            "Seg0711155346PM",
            "Seg0711154018PM",
            "Seg0711153432PM",
            "Seg0711140748PM",
            "Seg0711135636PM",
            "Seg0711131412PM",
            "Seg0711130857PM",
            "Seg0711130157PM",
            "Seg0711125338PM",
            "Seg0711113158AM",
            "customer",
            "cmstest7",
            "cmstest5",
            "cmstest3",
            "cmstest2",
            "gffyrth",
            "1testQR",
            "1testgallery",
            "121212"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "model": "analytics.request",
    "pk": 90,
    "fields": {
        "intent": "GetUserAccountInformation",
        "sub_intent": "",
        "request_text": "what is my balance",
        "response_text": "You have $111,111.11 and owe $111,111. Shall I break that down?",
        "session_id": "1v69yiptamgse1niap51zr2o9x154169081480766b2d6b7-d3ce-4166-9292-c4669a3dfc14",
        "user_id": "amzn1.ask.account.AHMFB2H7ZXMSCB5TLPYWCPBJGWGHFYQZ6OPPMEPQ7CT2LZXNPAFJMJELXXCCTEZ2JUE5PXRSBJHJTO3AVXT3C63AOEZLIEP3D3HIFBT5M23G4ORENFRT54AAK7I4X2HCORXJAB2UGQAHPE2TC75F2GWWZWSPO2CWEAZJJN7LJYFWEYHEJDLNQ6FSUD5LQWKBUC347K3IF32IV3I",
        "device_id": "amzn1.ask.account.AHMFB2H7ZXMSCB5TLPYWCPBJGWGHFYQZ",
        "device_type": "alexa",
        "device_model": "NA",
        "device_os": "alexa",
        "elapsed_time": 2013,
        "region": "NA",
        "latitude": 0,
        "longitude": 0,
        "date": "2018-11-08T15:32:40.090+0000",
        "ext_session_id": "",
        "ext_user_id": "",
        "score": 1,
        "platform_type": "alexa",
        "platform_user_id": "amzn1.ask.account.AHMFB2H7ZXMSCB5TLPYWCPBJGWGHFYQZ6OPPMEPQ7CT2LZXNPAFJMJELXXCCTEZ2JUE5PXRSBJHJTO3AVXT3C63AOEZLIEP3D3HIFBT5M23G4ORENFRT54AAK7I4X2HCORXJAB2UGQAHPE2TC75F2GWWZWSPO2CWEAZJJN7LJYFWEYHEJDLNQ6FSUD5LQWKBUC347K3IF32IV3I",
        "platform_conversation_id": "amzn1.echo-api.session.8586bff8-21a5-4336-9c9f-1c261362b89d",
        "registered": false,
        "segment_names": [
            "Test_Segment0731174425PM",
            "Test_Segment0731172344PM",
            "Test_Segment0731165438PM",
            "Test_Segment0731164321PM",
            "Test_Segment0731163349PM",
            "Test_Segment0731161939PM",
            "Test_Segment0731160424PM",
            "Test_Segment0730160925PM",
            "Test_Segment0730154627PM",
            "Test_Segment0730152806PM",
            "Test_Segment0730152328PM",
            "Test_Segment0730150203PM",
            "Test_Segment0730141720PM",
            "Test_Segment0730141304PM",
            "testseg",
            "Tester",
            "Test0730162816PM",
            "Test0730162304PM",
            "Test0730161031PM",
            "Test0730160632PM",
            "Test0730160502PM",
            "Seg0730154521PM",
            "Seg0730154322PM",
            "Seg0730153811PM",
            "Seg0730153303PM",
            "Seg0716231700PM",
            "Seg0716230741PM",
            "Seg0715080610AM",
            "Seg0715071857AM",
            "Seg0715070437AM",
            "Seg0715063307AM",
            "Seg0715054215AM",
            "Seg0715054027AM",
            "Seg0715053845AM",
            "Seg0715053646AM",
            "Seg0715053156AM",
            "Seg0715052407AM",
            "Seg0715045748AM",
            "Seg0714145246PM",
            "Seg0714135150PM",
            "Seg0714134041PM",
            "Seg0714012505AM",
            "Seg0714004152AM",
            "Seg0714002843AM",
            "Seg0713235444PM",
            "Seg0713230241PM",
            "Seg0713230030PM",
            "Seg0713225825PM",
            "Seg0713225548PM",
            "Seg0713225028PM",
            "Seg0713224159PM",
            "Seg0713220356PM",
            "Seg0711155346PM",
            "Seg0711154018PM",
            "Seg0711153432PM",
            "Seg0711140748PM",
            "Seg0711135636PM",
            "Seg0711131412PM",
            "Seg0711130857PM",
            "Seg0711130157PM",
            "Seg0711125338PM",
            "Seg0711113158AM",
            "customer",
            "cmstest7",
            "cmstest5",
            "cmstest3",
            "cmstest2",
            "gffyrth",
            "1testQR",
            "1testgallery",
            "121212"
        ]
    }
},
{...},
{...},
{...}
]
```

and would like to extract only certain objects from it (with `jq`) utilizing its selectors.

Say, return only the records where **.fields.user_id=="abc"**

Or, return only the records where **.fields.session_id=="1e2d3f"**

`select` seems to be the way to achieve this, but I'm not sure how to express the above with it given the JSON structure above.

[image]

The following produces empty result whereas it should return records for that session_id:

```
curl -X GET   'http://localhost:8090/xxx/api/v1/results?dr=last5days'   -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'   -H 'Postman-Token: f6b819d0-f4f6-4def-bccb-3967366779c7'   -H 'secret: 5a04bfef-39eb-435a-a0d0-b274592790bb' | jq '.[] | select(.fields.session_id=="1v69yiptamgse1niap51zr2o9x154169081480766b2d6b7-d3ce-4166-9292-c4669a3dfc14")'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 21785    0 21785    0     0   272k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  272k
$
```

Trying different combinations with jq's `entries` functions which don't quite work:

```
curl -X GET   'http://localhost:8080/xxx/api/v1/results?dr=last5days'   -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'   -H 'Postman-Token: f6b819d0-f4f6-4def-bccb-3967366779c7'   -H 'secret: 5a04bf34ef-39eb-435a-a0d0-b278765790bb' | jq  'with_entries(select(.value.pk==98))'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 31755    0 31755    0     0   127k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  127k
jq: error (at <stdin>:274): Cannot use number (9) as object key
```

Can someone please give me a hand creating a correct `jq` query?  TIA.

===

Trying to implement a suggestion expressed in the comments:

This `jq` expression:

```
map(select(.fields.user_id=="amzn1.ask.account.AHMFB2H7ZXMSCB5TLPYWCPBJGWGHFYQZ6OPPMEPQ7CT2LZXNPAFJMJELXXCCTEZ2JUE5PXRSBJHJTO3AVXT3C63AOEZLIEP3D3HIFBT5M23G4ORENFRT54AAK7I4X2HCORXJAB2UGQAHPE2TC75F2GWWZWSPO2CWEAZJJN7LJYFWEYHEJDLNQ6FSUD5LQWKBUC347K3IF32IV3I")) | length
```

seems to work in the JQ Playground (returns the correct count of **3**):

[image]

but when used on the command line, it returns a wrong result (and empty array of length **0**) :

```
$ curl -X GET   'http://localhost:8080/xxx/api/v1/results?dr=last5days'   -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'   -H 'Postman-Token: f6b819d0-f4f6-4def-bccb-3967366779c7'   -H 'secret: 5a04bfef-39eb-435a-a0d0-b271392790bb' | jq  'map(select(.fields.user_id=="amzn1.ask.account.AHMFB2H7ZXMSCB5TLPYWCPBJGWGHFYQZ6OPPMEPQ7CT2LZXNPAFJMJELXXCCTEZ2JUE5PXRSBJHJTO3AVXT3C63AOEZLIEP3D3HIFBT5M23G4ORENFRT54AAK7I4X2HCORXJAB2UGQAHPE2TC75F2GWWZWSPO2CWEAZJJN7LJYFWEYHEJDLNQ6FSUD5LQWKBUC347K3IF32IV3I")) | length'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 21785    0 21785    0     0  95630      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 95969
0
$
```

What am I still doing wrong?

======

As per suggestions in comments, the following query with debug returns JSON, but still doesn't produce correct counts:

```
$ curl -X GET   'http://localhost:8080/xxx/api/v1/results?dr=last5days'   -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'   -H 'Postman-Token: f6b819d0-f4f6-4def-bccb-3967366779c7'   -H 'secret: 5a04bfef-39eb-435a-a0d0-b271392790bb' | jq  ' debug | map(select(.fields.session_id=="1v69yiptamgse1niap51zr2o9x154169081480766b2d6b7-d3ce-4166-9292-c4669a3dfc14")) | length'
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You have an array of objects so map it selecting the objects of interest: `map(select(...))`

Comment: @JeffMercado: Thanks, I updated the question with some inconsistencies while implementing your suggestion.

Comment: You 'll need to verify that you're getting the expected json back. Stick a `debug` call at the beginning to see it and verify.

Comment: json is coming back from curl expression - I can see it.  Where should I put the `debug`, what's the syntax?

Comment: @JeffMercado: I put the query with debug statement which shows json returned, but no correct counts

Comment: It would return a 0 length if the curl output would return an empty array. Are you sure your API always return a JSON array filled with data?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using jq versions 1.6, 1.5, and 1.4, I've tested your jq program using the JSON version of the data, and all is well (on a Mac).
2. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - if you follow those guidelines, it should make debugging, communication, and/or life in general much easier for all concerned.
3. I'd suggest putting your jq program into a file and using the -f command-line option, at least while you're debugging this.